# Error with module signal in Python 2.7 (Win 64)

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

I have the following code:

```
import signal
    alive = 0    
    if alive > 0:                
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.0005)
     else:
         signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0)
```

Error:

```
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setitimer'
```

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 2):

[`signal.setitimer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer) is only available in **Unix**. You can't use it in Windows.

> `signal.setitimer(which, seconds[, interval])`
>
> ...
>
> **Availability: Unix.**